# Convert SVG to PDf using Pycairo

Tags: python, pdf, svg, pycairo

Can I convert an svg file to a PDF using the Python library pycairo?

`import cairo`

If it works somehow, someone can explain it. I haven't found anything on the internet so far.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://cairo.cairographics.narkive.com/uCbrrtHL/can-i-use-pycairo-to-convert-svg-file-to-pdf) can help you

Comment: thanks for the link ... I have already found it ... but I have no idea or I can not install rsvg which is why the link does not help me

Comment: pycairo official github.com sample -- https://github.com/pygobject/pycairo/blob/v1.19.1/examples/cairo_snippets/snippets_pdf.py

Comment: please note cairo does not have inbuilt facility to read an SVG file and render to a cairo surface, you must have another svg reader like `librsvg`